# How to list all clean files in a git repository?

Tags: git, status

Basically I am searching for the git equivalent to `hg status -c`:

> -c --clean               show only files without changes

Calling `git status` lists by default all 'dirty' files (i.e. files with changes) and untracked ones - which is fine.

But sometimes I need to display the complement - all (tracked) files without changes.

How do I accomplish this with git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ git ls-files -t | grep '^H'
```

The man page states that `-t` is deprecated - but I didn't find a better way. The alternatives the man page mentions does not seem to be sufficient for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
$ git ls-files -m  > /dev/shm/exclude && git ls-files | grep -v -x -f /dev/shm/exclude
```

Remember to delete the temporary file afterwards!